# Multiple autocomplete input fields not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

I have below code multiple input fields to show on single page with autocomplete feature. It works fine for one but fails for both of them. Please find my page codes here.It simply not showing suggestions for any of the fields while it was fine for `apexCIList` when used for only that field.

**Apex page**

Function code at top of page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript"> var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
  var apexCIList =[];
   var apexRepList =[];
  //alert(CIList);
   <apex:repeat value="{!CIList}" var="List">            
      apexCIList.push('{!List.name}');            
  </apex:repeat>

   <apex:repeat value="{!RepList}" var="List">            
      apexRepList.push('{!List.Rep_abv__r.name}');            
  </apex:repeat>





  //on Document ready
  j$(document).ready(function(){
      j$(".apexaccountautocomplete").autocomplete({
          source : apexCIList
          source : apexRepList
   });  


    j$("#button").click(function(){
      alert('somevalue');
     // var obj = document.getElementById("     {!$Component.iform.panel.apexaccountautocomplete}");
      alert(obj);
      });   

  });   


</script>
```

Reinitialised inside the pageblock to function during rerender.

```
<script>
            if(document.readyState == 'complete')
            {
               j$(".apexaccountautocomplete").autocomplete({
                      source : apexCIList
                      source : apexRepList
               });  


            }
            </script>
```

Inputfields display:

Compliance Incident Name

Apex controller get list values:

```
public String selectedCI{get;set;}
  public String selectedrep{get;set;}

public void changeEditable(){
    System.debug('selectedCI@@'+selectedCI);
    applyfiler();
   isEditable = isEditable ? false:true;
}



public Boolean isEditable {get; private set;}



//public void changeEditable(){   == setInputvalue

public list<Compliance_incident_abv__c > getCIList(){
    return [select id,name,Owner.name from Compliance_incident_abv__c limit 25];
}

public list<Compliance_incident_abv__c > getRepList(){
    return [select id,Rep_abv__r.name,name from Compliance_incident_abv__c limit 25];
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 document.ready blocks?

Comment: Can I keep two sources in one block?

Comment: @SFDC_Learner of course you do and you should.

Comment: It's not working. I checked just now :(

Comment: I have updated my latest code accordingly here.

Comment: @LanceShi  Can you please help me here?